# Active or Passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

> This book is to read.
>
> This book is to be read.

Which one is ok?

"This book' is not the doer, but the receiver of the action. This is the object of the action if the voice is kept active, thus if is made the subject of the action, the sentence should be in passive voice.

Is this right?

Comment: Many transitive verbs can be used in a so-called "middle" sense in English, so in some contexts you can talk about the book reading, rather than being read. But these are usually when you are talking about what the experience of reading is like, for example "This book reads as though it had been written by a classical scholar". But when referring to the activity of reading, it needs to be passive if the book is to be the subject.

Answer (score -1):

This is the grammatically correct passive form:

> This book will be read.

Comment: That changes the meaning significantly.

Answer (score -1):

The second one is correct.

Active: They are to read the book.

Passive: **The book is to be read** (by them)